# Removing last element in LinkedList (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am writing a function to delete the last node in a linked list. This is what I have, and other code I've found online searching for a solution is very similar (I have found several), but when I execute it it creates some sort of infinite loop when deleting the last element of a linked list (it deletes other elements just fine though).

Here is the code I imagine is causing a problem:

```
void delete_final(Node* head){
    if(head == NULL) {
        return; }
    if(head->next == NULL) {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        return;
    }  
//other code 
}
```

I imagine it's an issue with the memory (particularly after the delete head; statement), but I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help or an explanation for why this doesn't work (I possibly don't have a very good understanding of pointers and memory in C++, I'm just starting with it)

Here is my Node code for reference:

```
struct Node {
  int key;
  Node* next;
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you are never actually assigning null to the real head, you have a copy in that function

Comment: You should go to the least element, so if head->next !=NULL delete_final(head->next); and so on...

Comment: @sp2danny could you elaborate a bit? Are you saying the statement head = NULL; isn't touching the actual head? How can I change that so the specific object I'm interested in is assigned to NULL?

Comment: `Node *head` is a copy of the pointer you passed to `delete_final` function, lets assume its `param`. What `head` contains is the pointer to what `param` points to. So when you write `head = NULL` you are actually just changing what `head` points to. Not what param points to.

Comment: changing the parameter declaration to `Node*& head` should suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original code:

```
void delete_final(Node* head){
    if(head == NULL) {
        return; }
    if(head->next == NULL) {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        return;
    }  
//other code 
}
```

The "other code" is not specified, but if the list has exactly one node then the above code will

- delete that first node, and
- update the local pointer `head`, which doesn't update the actual argument since it was *passed by value*.

As a result the calling code will be left with a **dangling pointer** in this case, a pointer pointing to a destroyed object, or to where such an object once was. Any use of such a pointer is Undefined Behavior. It might appear to work, or crash, or just silently cause dirty words tattoo to appear on your forehead – anything…

---

One fix is to pass the first-pointer *by reference*:

```
void delete_final(Node*& head){
    if(head == nullptr) {
        return; }
    if(head->next == nullptr) {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
        return;
    }  
//other code 
}
```

---

A nice helper function for dealing with linked lists, is `unlink`:

```
auto unlink( Node*& p )
    -> Node*
{
    Node* const result = p;
    p = p->next;
    return result;
}
```

The *implementation* is perhaps a bit subtle, but all you need to remember to use it is that it updates the pointer you pass as argument, which should be either a first-node pointer or a `next` pointer in the list, and returns a pointer to the unlinked node.

So e.g. you can do

```
delete unlink( p_first );
```